# How to call worker role permission through role_permission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing a role permission edit function. It didn't have error but the logic of the code have some problem.

It didn't update the permission but update whole role_permission so it came out like image 1 & 2, it keep update many times.

I need to get the worker role_permission then check if that the permission already have?, if have then no need to add, if no then need to add(update). How can i check it at role controller update there?

Role controller

```
def edit
 @role = Role.find(params[:id])
 @role.company_id = params[:company_id]
 @permissions = Permission.all
end

def update
 @role = Role.find(params[:id])
 @company_id = Company.find(params[:role][:company_id])
 if @role.update!(role_params)
   permission_ids = params[:permission_ids]
   permission_ids.each do |permission_id|
     RolePermission.update(role_id: @role.id, permission_id: permission_id)
   end
   flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @role
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit Roles") %>
<h1 class="dashboard">Update Role</h1>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
  <%= form_with(model: @role, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= @permissions.each do |permission|%>
   <%= check_box_tag 'permission_ids[]', permission.id%>
   <%= f.label :permission_name, permission.name %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :company_id , value: 2%>

  <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-secondary bottom" %>
 <% end %>
 </div>
</div>
```

RolePermission migration table

```
create_table "role_permissions", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer "role_id"
 t.integer "permission_id"
 t.integer "company_id"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

[parameter pass in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk8Ik.png)

[parameter pass in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIOeG.png)

Update

roles controller (role_params)

```
def role_params
  params.require(:role).permit(:name, :company_id)
end
```

console logs when update role

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrb2x.png)

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2IkO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hi since you want Update/Add permissions related to roles.

can do it with the help of `first_or_initialize`:

```
def update
 @role = Role.find(params[:id])
 @company_id = Company.find(params[:role][:company_id])
 if @role.update!(role_params)
   permission_ids = params[:permission_ids]
   permission_ids.each do |permission_id|
     role_permissions = @role.role_permissions.where(permission_id: permission_id).first_or_initialize
     role_permissions.save
   end
   flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @role
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Read more about [first_or_initialize](https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_initialize)

OR

you should have the following associations with the below models:

```
# role.rb
has_many :role_permissions, dependent: :destroy
has_many :permissions, through: :role_permissions, source: :permission 

# role_permission.rb
belongs_to :role
belongs_to :permission
```

Then in your roles_controller.rb should have below:

```
def update
 @role = Role.find(params[:id])
 @company_id = Company.find(params[:role][:company_id])
 if @role.update!(role_params)
    flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
    redirect_to @role
  else
   render 'edit'
  end
end


def role_params
  params.require(:role).permit(:name, :company_id, permission_ids: [])
end
```

Comment: Hi, i have update my code with this and it have update the permission if the worker didn't have and won't add when worker have already. But if like there have 4 permission, now worker A have three permission(exp: view, create and edit) Now, i edit worker A just can view and create, but after update the edit permission will still available at there. How to fixed that?

Comment: what I assume is that suppose a user has 3 permissions(view, create, edit). and you are passing 2(view, create), then edit should be removed. right?

Comment: sorry, maybe i say wrong. Is like this,  i have a checkbox to let admin access what permission can give to role. Suppose role(manager) can (view, create and edit) but admin want to edit that role only can (view and create), so the permission there should only have view and create.

Comment: can you add console logs in questions while updating roles, so that I can update it in above answer ?

Comment: also add `role_params` action from `roles_controller.rb`

Comment: Hi, i have update my question, is that the code you want?

Comment: Please check updated anser.

Comment: Hi, i have try but the second one didn't edit anything, it will still be there